# transform function that receives a fixed number of arguments to a varargs scala

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

Is it there a generic way to transform a fixed size argument function to a function that does the same thing, but operates receives the operations in a `Seq`

For example, a simple add function

```
def add(x: Int, y:Int) = x + y
```

How can i generically transform it to:

```
def add2(x: Int*) = x(0) + x(1)
```

The interface to convert the two representations should be more generically possible and accept a variable number of arguments.

Note that i do not want to perform this transformation in run time.

The point is, i want the user of my library to give me functions of the type `def add(x: Int, y:Int) = x + y`, which then i will generically transform to  `def add2(x: Int*) = x(0) + x(1)` in order to be able to use them with my engine, which expects the second representation

Comment: What do you mean by generically transform? When? At run-time?

Comment: I would look in following directions (in order of priority): - `scala.Dynamic`, - Scala `macro`, - Aspect Oriented Programming, - code generations

Comment: Could you please show the interface of your library? How would you accept the methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way, maybe is helpful for you, you can try to use the [scala macro](http://scalameta.org/). and [paradise](https://github.com/scalameta/paradise)

1.Need to add paradise in your compiler, like:

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.scalameta" % "paradise" % "3.0.0-M5" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

2.add scala meta in dependency, like:

```
"org.scalameta" %% "scalameta" % "1.3.0"
```

3.Create custom **AutoVarargs** macro(it should be in a **separate module** with your usage):

```
import scala.meta._

class AutoVarargs extends StaticAnnotation {
  inline def apply(defn: Any): Any = meta {
    defn match {
      case q"def add(...$paramss): Int = $expr" =>
        q"""
          def add(i: Int*): Int = {
            i.sum
          }
        """
    }
  }
}
```

4.use it:

```
object MetaMacro extends App{
  @AutoVarargs
  def add(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y
  println(add(2, 3))
  println(add(2, 3, 4, 5))
}
```

5.after compile:

```
  @AutoVarargs
  def add(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y
```

this will be auto transform to:

```
  def add(x: Int*): Int = x.sum
```

so for user of your library, they can use this **annotation** with target method.